# Magento allow user to change theme colors via admin panel

Tags: magento

Ok so I want to allow the end user (who most likely won't know anything about code) to be able to change the theme colors I'm creating. I saw you can create custom variables, but it's not really efficient to put your CSS as a php file.

So how do I go about this where the user can just put the hex code of a color for the navigation background or button background or whatever.. via the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by adding a customer attribute and letting your customer change it.

Adding a customer attribute can be achieved with this sort of method:

```
 public function addCustomerAttribute($params){

     try{

        $setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
        $setup->addAttribute('customer', $params['code'], array(
                     'type' => $params['type'] ,
                     'input' => $params['input'],
                     'label' => $params['name'],
                     'global' => $params['scope'],
                     'visible' => 1,
                     'required' => $params['required'],
                     'user_defined' => 1,
                     'default' => $params['defaultvalue'],
                     'visible_on_front' => $params['visible_on_front'],
                     'used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit')
        ));

        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
             ->getAttribute('customer', $params['code'] )
             ->setData(
                'used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit')
             )
             ->save();

        return true;

     }catch(Exception $e){
        throw new Exception('Probleme de création d\'attribut client ' . $e->getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Then if your customer is logged in, just let him change the value and save it.

You can then retrieve it with

```
$customerColor = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getAttributecode()
```

and use this value to set CSS classes on your templates